# What is the best way to store CTime in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, ctime

Using the shell command I get the following output with the CTime for a particular file: `1665579792.879379`.
Now I'm thinking about the best way to save this value to msql database, and what type of column to create.
Because when I do something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
`ctime` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

I lose all the digits after the dot.

Comment: why not store it as datetime?

Comment: You can use `varchar` and convert it later if necessary.

Comment: @IbrahimHammed storing it as `varchar` would only help in preserving representation. If its being used in queries with joins and clauses like `between`, it provides little to no benefit.

Comment: use `decimal(19,6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> create table mytable ( d datetime(6) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable set d = from_unixtime(1665579792.879379);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----------------------------+
| d                          |
+----------------------------+
| 2022-10-12 06:03:12.879379 |
+----------------------------+
```

The digits after the dot are normal. They are microseconds.

If you don't want to store microseconds, use `datetime` instead of `datetime(6)`. This will truncate the fractional part of the seconds, and store just the time in whole seconds.

```
mysql> create table mytable ( d datetime );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable set d = from_unixtime(1665579792.879379);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2022-10-12 06:03:13 |
+---------------------+
```